# .keyup() up and down arrows in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I'm trying to attach a `.keyup(e)` to the up and down arrows. It works fine in Firefox but not in Safari. All of the other arrows work fine in Safari.

```
$(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {

        if (event.keyCode == 37) 
        {
        // go left
            $('.left').click();
        } 
        else if (event.keyCode == 39) 
        {
        // go right
            $('.right').click();
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == 38) 
        {
        // next project
            $('a.up div.arrow').click();
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == 40) 
        {
        // previous project
            $('a.down div.arrow').click();
        }
        else if (event.keyCode == 32) 
        {
        // info
            $('aside').click();
        }
    });
```

EDIT:
A link to a working demo of my website — http://www.ryan-neil.com

Should've added that sooner...

Answer (score 2):

**Working Demo** please try here I am on OSX lion safari and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/DRgRv/1/

So click on the grey box and then use up and down arrow keys to navigate:

d'uh don't forget to up vote and accept if this helps.

**code**

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
    case 37:
        $('div').stop().animate({
            left: '-=10'
        }); //left arrow key
        break;
    case 38:
        $('div').stop().animate({
            top: '-=10'
        }); //up arrow key
        break;
    case 39:
        $('div').stop().animate({
            left: '+=10'
        }); //right arrow key
        break;
    case 40:
        $('div').stop().animate({
            top: '+=10'
        }); //bottom arrow key
        break;
    }
})​
```

Comment: It works on jsfiddle in Safari, but when added to my code it throws the images off. I changed the id's and .animate() to .click()

Answer (score 1):

which version of safari ar you using

[jquery support](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility)About Browser Compatibility

jQuery actively supports these browsers:

```
Firefox Current - 1 version
Internet Explorer 6+
Safari Current - 1 version
Opera Current - 1 version
Chrome Current - 1 version
```

Any problem with them should be considered and reported as a bug in jQuery.

There are known problems with:

```
Mozilla Firefox 1.0.x
Internet Explorer 1.0-5.x
Safari 1.0-2.0.1
Opera 1.0-9.x
Konqueror
```

jQuery generally works with Konqueror and Firefox 1.0.x, but there may be some unexpected bugs since we do not test them as regularly.

you can test key events

[try test here](http://www.ryancooper.com/resources/keycode.asp)

[or here](http://asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html)

you still can try hacking it like this From another post in stackoverflow

Keypress is a confusing event. While keydown and keyup will tell you which specific key on your keyboard is down or just came back up, the keypress event is supposed to tell you what character would appear on the screen, that's why the jquery documentation that you referenced says:

```
For example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup, but as 97 by keypress.
```

To make things worse Safari doesn't trigger keypress events for stuff that doesn't write something onto the screen—that’s why arrow keys won't work. Firefox, however, does trigger keypress events for arrow keys. Both are reasonable implementations of the spec, so don’t expect either to change. That's why there was the suggestion to just stick with keydown or keyup.

However, it looks like you want to take advantage of how the keypress event repeats (in Firefox) when a key is held down and you want to do this with an arrow key. If that's the case, you need to write a handler that looks at both keydown and keypress. here are the two different ways browsers react to an arrow key being held down:

***Firefox** registers a keydown event and also repeats keypress events 
 (note: just hitting  the key once will register both a keydown and a keypress event)

***Safari** registers a keydown event and repeats the keydown event
 A quick hack to make that work reasonably well for arrow keys and get the key repeats to  work is:

```
function moveItem(evt) {
    // do something with `this` and evt.keyCode here...
}

$(document.documentElement)
    .keypress(function(evt) {
        if ($.data(this, '_lastKeyEvent') != 'keydown') {
            // since firefox will do both a keydown and a keypress for the first
            // keydown, we ignore the very first keypress
            moveItem.call(this, evt);
        }
        $.data(this, '_lastKeyEvent', 'keypress');
    })
    .keydown(function(evt) {
        moveItem.call(this, evt);
        $.data(this, '_lastKeyEvent', 'keydown');
    });
```

Comment: It's Version 5.1.5. I've read of other people having problems with char codes on key press as well. I'll report it as a bug. Thanks

Comment: Left, right and spacebar still work with this code, but the up and down arrows are still unusable in Safari.